# How to sum specific elements of a mixed Kotlin collection

Tags: kotlin

If I had a mixed type Kotlin collection how would I be able to access and sum specific elements within that list. for example:

```
var mixedList = listOf("dog", "cat", 7, "Apple", "Orange", 10)
```

elements[2] and [5] are Ints. So how would I access and add them together for 17?

Comment: If you are sure that they are `Int`s, then `mixedList[2] as Int + mixedList[5] as Int`, and this will throw an exception if they turn out not to be Ints.  But the more important question is, why do you have a mixed list in the first place?

Comment: I used ::class.simpleName to make sure they are Ints. I know its better to not use mixed lists. I was just practicing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Taking a step back, there is almost no situation where you would ever need a mixed collection. It's a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested this problem can be easily solved using  [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/filter-is-instance.html) and [`sum`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sum.html) functions defined for `Iterable` as well as `Sequence` in kotlin statndard library. but one small, yet very important detail is performance implication of `Iterable` vs `Sequence`

### For small data set

```
val sum = yourList.filterIsInstance<Int>.sum()
// In first pass list is filtered, in second pass sum is calculated
```

### For large data sets

```
val sum = yourList.asSequence().filterIsInstance<Int>().sum()
// Item is filtered and added to sum in single pass
```

Comment: If you want to be exhaustive, you can also just use a loop, without even the sequence overhead: `var sum = 0; for (item in mixedList) { if (item is Int) { sum += item } }`

Comment: true, but in this particular case sequence option will generate almost identical code, without having to take a hit on code readability

Answer (score 2):

```
fun main() {
    val mixedList = listOf("dog", "cat", 7, "Apple", "Orange", 10)
    val sum = mixedList.filterIsInstance<Int>().sum()
    println(sum)
}
```

Output:

```
17
```

Comment: Optimal solution for this problem should only cost O(n), while this costs O(n X m), where n is the size of original list and m is the size of filtered list, sequence should be used when dealing with large data set

Comment: Surely it's O(n + m), both in time and memory?  (And since m <= n, that's simply O(n).)  For big lists, a sequence would give a small saving; but for small ones, the sequence overhead would probably dominate.

Comment: @mightyWOZ IMO commenting "consider sequences for multiple operations on large lists" would have been more appropriate than your above comment plus duplicating this answer with a sequence example added. I'm not even sure if this (and thus your answer too) answers the question because the OP said "specific elements" rather than "all integers".

Comment: @gidds  That was supposed to be O(n + m), thank you for correction. but I don't agree with your point that `For big lists, a sequence would give a small saving`. there is nothing small about the performance gain, apart from the reduced iteration with sequence, Iterable version will also create multiple(depending on the number of intermediate operations) in-flight data structures, I suggest you run some bench marks with large data sets and see the difference for yourself.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip  As I said in my answer, you are missing an important detail in your answer. when confronted with this kind of problem most of the people, like you did simply use the Iterable version and don't consider or are aware of the existence of sequence version. knowing that you have other options that might work better is vital to writing good software

Comment: @mightyWOZ I said a small performance gain, because it doesn't reduce the overall order.  Both versions take O(n) time; the sequence version takes O(1) memory, and the non-sequence O(n) memory. The difference in memory usage is significant, but the overall order is O(n) in both cases, so converting it to use a sequence is unlikely to give radical improvements unless the app is creating enough temporary objects that GC time is significant.

Comment: @gidds If I had a function with runtime `100000000n+c` and another with `1n+c`, then by your reasoning there is not going to be any radical difference between the performance because they are both `O(n)`, this is an understandable but serious mistake, you seem to think hidden constants in big O doesn't really matter. which is wrong on every level. In practical situations, one should know about the hidden constants. certainly a loop executed once and a loop executed million times is O(n), but please don't conclude that executing a loop million times has no significant performance impact